# Session sometimes timesout too quick

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am noticing session timeouts on my asp.net mvc web app randomly without browser being incative for for more than few minutes.

My understanding is the default timeout should be 20mins. But sometimes I get a timeout in couple minutes or even less than that. For example after browsing on the site for a while I might get a session timeout when i refresh a page very soon after I enter the page.

This is very random but I have seen this happen quite a few times now and I am not sure how I can trace this to see why I loose sessions every once in a while whithout browser being inactive long.

I checked my web.config an no timeout value is defined there so I assume it should be 20mins.

Hard to debug as this does not occur regularly..

Comment: Are you experiencing this while in development/debug mode or actually seeing it in production?

Comment: Any chance web.config is being modified?  That causes the application to reload, breaking sessions.

Comment: @Steven: right. or if you are running the application through Visual Studio development server and you modify your code, save, and refresh browser, automatic recompilation may similarly force the application to reload.

Comment: is this a web server? web farm? what kind of session are you using.. inproc, out of proc?

Answer (score 0):

1. There's an IIS setting for timeout. check it also
2. Maybe your application calls session abandon?
3. You can register session end handler to write to log on the server, to see exactly when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

IIS overrides your web.config. 
Go into IIS (this is for IIS 6) 
Right click your website,  properties, asp.net tab.
Click Edit Configurtation button on bottom, ASP.Net Configuration Settings, State Management, set your timeout here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating any files in the bin folder, that can also cause the application to restart.

There are a number of other causes too, try googling .....

> causes for asp.net web application to restart

I got a couple of hits that list the possible causes.